# Design Elements No Longer Visible After Pressing Undo: Visual Studio Windows Form

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

Total newbie all this, so may need responses to be simplified to my level of learning.

Yesterday I pressed undo after  copying and pasting a huge chunk of my design that ended up not including some of the checkboxes I had thought were copied over. When I pressed undo ask the design elements on my form had shifted upwards some off screen and inaccessible. I used ctrl+a to select everything on the screen and move it down ward which worked except the very first group box on the form the buttons inside the group box, and a rich text box and button located outside the group box no longer show up. When I press ctr+a I can see the outline of my now invisible group box and buttons but can't do anything with it- when I copy and paste into a new form it still shows as invisible and when I try to select just the single design elements using my mouse nothing gets selected and the Properties Box just shows me the properties for the Form as a whole.

How do I get access to my now invisible design elements (I've already coded for them all so am resistant to having to just redo the design and then edit the code).

Secondary, does anyone have any idea on why this might have happened and how to prevent it from occurring again because I'm now paranoid about using the undo button.

For info: running visual studio 2022 using windows forms. Picture  for reference so you can see how my invisible items show as selected after ctrl+a.

[My invisible design elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRrU7.jpg)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using source control is rather important to recover from major mishaps.  Use View > Other Windows > Document Layout, it lets you select controls that are off the form and makes it easy to correct Z-order problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the position size of the controls you copied exceeds the size of the container. If the container you use is a panel, I copied four controls but the control exceeds the scope of the panel.

[image]

At this time, some of my controls will have the problem you described, they will be covered and cannot be displayed

You have two ways to operate on overridden controls:

1. If you know the name of the control, you can directly select the control you want to operate in the property bar

[image]

2. The panel has a property named AutoScroll, set it to true, then the panel will appear as follows:

[image]

Comment: Form is set for auto scroll and I was able just now to see several group boxes that got moved onto one another and were preventing visibility. The very first group box however, continues to remain invisible as well as all the items in in and only shows up when ctr a pressed. If I just click on the area where it should be so I can edit the properties nothing happens

Comment: @ZeanaBey I'm sorry that I didn't express clearly, not only the AutoScroll of the form is set to true, but you can also set AutoScroll to true for other containers. And it is impossible to use the first method without a corresponding control, which is a very versatile method. Of course, I very much agree with Hans Passant's suggestion that source code management is important for a programmer. If my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people